# How to register ServletContextListener in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, servletcontextlistener

Hello I'm trying to rewrite my old code to use Spring Boot. 
I have one listener `public class ExecutorListener implements ServletContextListener`.

How can I register this listener for Spring Boot? 
I've tried:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new ExecutorListener());
    }

}
```

But the `contextInitialized` method is not called.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try couple of things:
Register `ExecutorListener` as a `@Bean` explicitly:

```
@Bean
public ExecutorListener executorListener() {
   return new ExecutorListener();
}
```

or

You can try it with explicitly creating ServletRegistrationBean:

```
@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServlet servlet=new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.getServletContext().addListener(new ExecutorListener());
    return  servlet;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/rest/v1/*");
    registrationBean
            .setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);


    return registrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If using an embedded container, there will soon be a third option if using SpringBoot 1.3.0+ 
Annotate your `ServletContextListener` implementation with `@WebListener` from servlet spec 3, then annotate one of your Spring `@Configuration` classes with the new `@ServletComponentScan` (and optionally tell it which packages to scan for filters, servlets and listeners).

Only available in 1.3.0+ at the moment though: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletComponentScan.html

Docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners

Comment: This only works, when using the embedded server: cf. [ServletComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletComponentScan.html).

Answer (score 5):

In case you prefer auto discovery using annotations only, make your `ExecutorListener` implement the `ServletContextInitializer` and e.g. annotate it with `javax.annotation.ManagedBean`. From there, just implement the `onStartup` method:

```
@ManagedBean
public final class ExecutorListener implements ServletContextInitializer {
  ...
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to create a class implements `ServletContextListener` and add `@WebListner` to the top which will tell Springboot this is a ServletContextListener , then add `@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = "xxx")` in `SpringBootApplication` to actually register it into the container

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ...
    }
}
```