# Don't know how to register ServletContextListener in Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I am trying to **rebuild** my **Spring-based** web app on **Spring boot** beacuse I need it to be running on **embedded Jetty**.

I imported all my spring-related **xml configuration files** to spring boot using **@ImportResource** annotation, but I also need my **ServletContextListener** implementation to be registered in Spring Boot cause it does some important stuff.

How can I do it? I read [the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394862/how-to-register-servletcontextlistener-in-spring-boot) with the same question on the site but have not found clear answer there.

**SpringBootApplication**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml", "classpath:spring/spring-database.xml", "classpath:spring/spring-security.xml"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class DvdExchangeSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DvdExchangeSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**My ServletContextListener**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;


public class WebAppPropertiesListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String rootPath = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        System.setProperty("webroot", rootPath);

        DBInitializer.initializeDB();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }

}
```

Even if I try to follow some of [mentioned advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394862/how-to-register-servletcontextlistener-in-spring-boot) all I get is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-database.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'webroot' in string value "jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}/WEB-INF/classes/DBStorage/testdb"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webroot' in string value "jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}/WEB-INF/classes/DBStorage/testdb"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:177) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:152) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.dvdexchange.DvdExchangeSpringBootApplication.main(DvdExchangeSpringBootApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webroot' in string value "jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}/WEB-INF/classes/DBStorage/testdb"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2016-07-11 21:49:18.691  INFO 540 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/D:/Downloads/DVDExchangespringboot/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.36/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jetty/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jetty-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-servlets-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-continuation-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-http-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-util-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-io-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-webapp-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-xml-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-security-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.2.17.v20160517/websocket-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.2.17.v20160517/websocket-common-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.2.17.v20160517/websocket-api-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.2.17.v20160517/websocket-client-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.2.17.v20160517/websocket-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.2.17.v20160517/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-annotations-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-plus-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.2.17.v20160517/jetty-jndi-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.1/asm-5.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.1/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.1/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.2.17.v20160517/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.2.17.v20160517.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.3.3/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.3/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.3/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.7/jackson-annotations-2.6.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-taglibs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-taglibs-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.0.Final/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.0/classmate-1.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.18/slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.18/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.18.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.6/logback-classic-1.1.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.0.27/apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1.M0/jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Artyom/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.0.27/apache-el-8.0.27.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202016.1.1/lib/idea_rt.jar]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Help me please!

**UPDATE 1 (11.07.2016)**

My **application.properties** already contains the following:

```
server.contextPath=/DVDExchange
webroot = ${webroot}
```

But it does not work. The same error occurs.

**UPDATE 2 (11.07.2016)**

These are my db connection configurations:

**spring-database.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- HSQLDB data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}/classes/DBStorage/testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="SA" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>User.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Disk.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Takenitem.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.dvdexchange.dao.impl.UserDAOHibernateImpl"/>

    <bean id="myUserServiceImpl" class="com.dvdexchange.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
                      expression="execution(* com.dvdexchange.service.*ServiceImpl.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}/classes/DBStorage/testdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">SA</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->


        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Disk.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Takenitem.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**UPDATE 3 (12.07.2016)**

After solving db storing problem I still can not make my web app work as needed. This is the error I get on start of my app:

[image: error 404]

Comment: Ok I see the issue now maybe. Try to add the webroot property to application.properties or application.yml. Btw you can set the context path with property server.context-path look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties)

Comment: @bilak I updated question for you. Don't even know why the app does not work.

Comment: but this line `webroot = ${webroot}` is pointing to placeholder ${webroot} which was not set before. Try `webroot=${server.contextPath}`

Comment: @bilak I did how you suggested but it does not work. I updated the question to make it more clear. Maybe I could just upload 2 versions of my project (original on external Jetty and this current one rebuilded for Spring boot but not working) and you could find out solution? How do you think?

Comment: Why are you trying to store db inside webapp - it will be deleted when you redeploy application.. I mean this config `jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}/classes/DBStorage/testdb`. For testing try to store it somewhere to the /tmp or some existing path on the computer where are you running your application. For example something like `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/tmp/testdb`.

Comment: @bilak Because it must be deployed and working on any PC. When my application was running on external Jetty - these configuration worked fine for both spring and hibernate and webroot was `D:\Stuff\Java\DVDExchange\target\DVDExchange`.  But after rebulding my web app to spring boot webroot changed to `C:\Windows\Temp\jetty-docbase.2847319914763232.8080`. SO the problem is I don't know how to make spring and hibernate find db in the same directory using spring boot

Comment: @bilak I did how you said and seems like it works. Anyway my app still does not work as needed - look at the update 3 of my question please!

Comment: I think you could create a separate issue for this, I'm not the one who works with spring frontends. Maybe you can also look at viewresolver setup ([try to look here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-example/)).

Comment: @bilak Thank you anyway!